# Determining the Jordan decomposition of a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, jordan-normal-form, generalized-eigenvector

$
\newcommand{\m}[1]{\left( \begin{matrix} #1 \end{matrix} \right)}
\newcommand{\l}{\lambda}
$
I have the matrix given as follows:

$$A := \m{ -2 & -1 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & -4 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & -5 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 }$$

I wish to determine the Jordan decomposition for $A$. So far I have determined the following:

- $A$ has characteristic polynomial $p(\l) = -(\l+3)^4$. ([Wolfram agrees](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=characteristic+polynomial+%7B+%7B-2%2C-1%2C1%2C2%7D%2C%7B1%2C-4%2C1%2C2%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C-5%2C4%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C-1%2C-1%7D+%7D) up to that leading coefficient which isn't relevant.) Thus, it has a single eigenvalue, $\l = -3$, with multiplicity $4$.
- The matrix $A+3I$ has nullity $2$. Thus the algebraic and geometric multiplicities of $3$ differ, making it not diagonalizable in the traditional sense. [(Wolfram agrees.)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=null+space+%7B+%7B1%2C-1%2C1%2C2%7D%2C%7B1%2C-1%2C1%2C2%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C-2%2C4%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C-1%2C2%7D+%7D+)
- I have found that there exist two ordinary eigenvectors for $A$, i.e. vectors $\vec p$ such that $(A+3I)\vec p = \vec 0$. Namely, the following:
  $$v = (-4,0,2,1) \qquad w = (1,1,0,0)$$
  ([Wolfram agrees](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=null+space+%7B+%7B1%2C-1%2C1%2C2%7D%2C%7B1%2C-1%2C1%2C2%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C-2%2C4%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C-1%2C2%7D+%7D+)  with this being the basis of the null space.)
- I still need two generalized eigenvectors to fill my roster. So let's start with squaring $A+3I$. In such a case, there is a single vector, by my eyes, which fits. Using the alternate characterization of generalizing a specific eigenvector, e.g. finding $v'$ such that $(A+3I)v' = v$ (or $w$), we can see that $v$ won't work in this way, but if we do it for $w$ we can obtain
  $$w' = (1,0,0,0)$$
  [Wolfram does list this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=null+space+%7B+%7B1%2C-1%2C1%2C2%7D%2C%7B1%2C-1%2C1%2C2%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C-2%2C4%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C-1%2C2%7D+%7D+%5E2) in the basis of the null space of $(A+3I)^2$. There isn't an issue picking $w'$ this way so far as far as I know: [Wolfram agrees](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=linearly+independent+%28-4%2C0%2C2%2C1%29%2C%281%2C1%2C0%2C0%29%2C%281%2C0%2C0%2C0%29) that the three are linearly independent. Thus, this is the only additional eigenvector we get from $(A+3I)^2$.
- To find a fourth (generalized) eigenvector, $w''$, we will note that $(A+3I)^3$ is the zero matrix and thus has null space of $\Bbb R^4$. (Again, [Wolfram agrees](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=null+space+%7B+%7B1%2C-1%2C1%2C2%7D%2C%7B1%2C-1%2C1%2C2%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C-2%2C4%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C-1%2C2%7D+%7D+%5E3).) Thus, we can pick any vector we please that is linearly independent from the rest. As it happens, $w'' = (0,0,1,1)$ is such a vector. (Again, [Wolfram agrees.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=linearly+independent+%28-4%2C0%2C2%2C1%29%2C%281%2C1%2C0%2C0%29%2C%281%2C0%2C0%2C0%29%2C%280%2C0%2C1%2C1%29))
- From the structure of this problem, we see two Jordan chains:
  $$v \qquad w \to w' \to w''$$
  Thus, the Jordan form $J$ of $A$ should have one $1 \times 1$ block and one $3 \times 3$ block, each associated with $\l = -3$. Thus, we will have
  $$J = 
  \m{ -3 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & -3 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & -3 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & -3 }$$
- Thus, we have our four eigenvectors to form the matrix $P$ such that $A = PJP^{-1}$.
  $$P := \big[ \; v \; \big| \; w \; \big| \; w' \; \big| \; w'' \; \big] = \m{
  -4 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  2 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 & 1}$$

This is where I get confused. Performing the calculation of $PJP^{-1}$ does not give me *quite* $A$ back. Per [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B+%7B-4%2C1%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B2%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D+%7D+*+%7B+%7B-3%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C-3%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C-3%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C-3%7D+%7D+*+%28inverse+%7B+%7B-4%2C1%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B2%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D+%7D%29),

$$PJP^{-1} = \m{
-2 & -1 & 3 & -2 \\
1 & -4 & 4 & -4 \\
0 & 0 & -3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -3}$$

yet I'm not entirely sure where I've gone wrong. I've been trying to resolve this discrepancy for days with no luck, no matter what I look up. In fact, [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Jordan+decomposition+%7B+%7B-2%2C-1%2C1%2C2%7D%2C%7B1%2C-4%2C1%2C2%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C-5%2C4%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C-1%2C-1%7D+%7D) gives a very different decomposition: namely, they claim

$$P = \m{1/4 & 8 & 2 & 0\\
5/4 & 8 & 2 & 0\\
1/2 & 0 & 4 & 0\\
1/4 & 0 & 2 & 1}$$

but at least we agree on $J$...

Can anyone enlighten me as to what I might have done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two directions frequently taught. One way is to write down the genuine eigenvector for each block, then trickle down to the consistent generalized. That is reliable, but tends to introduce lots of fractions when the matrix elements and eigenvalues are integers.

I like going from the ground up; the fractions wait until $P^{-1},$  where $J = P^{-1} A P.$  Here $(A + 3 I)^3 = 0$ but $(A+3I)^2 \neq 0.$  We need three column vectors $p,q,r$  such that $(A+3I)^3 r = 0$ but  $(A+3I)^2 r \neq 0.$  I took $r = (0,0,0,1)^T .$  Then $q = (A+3I) r = (2,2,4,2)^T $  and $p = (A+3I) q = (8,8,0,0)^T .$ Thus $p$ is a genuine eigenvector

The first column of $P$ is another genuine eigenvector

Comment: Thanks for your help! I also really like your way of determining the generalized eigenvectors. It's contrary to every way I've been taught, but it just feels so much less messier and flows so much better to me!